# Difference in Response Code ,Android M permission

Tags: android

On a single Activity I have onActivityResult and onRequestPermissionsResult. I have different request codes for each functionality.

But , Request Code in onRequestPermissionResult is coming out to be 513 instead of 1 which I am sending.

This is only happening in the activity with both the above methods.

I have different request codes for both of them. Are they conflict in some way or the other?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Ever figure anything out on this? Same issue but 515

Answer (score 0):

This is old but figured I would answer in case anyone else runs into this. The issue is when you have onRequestPermissionResult in a fragment you must also call

```
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
```

From the activity onRequestPermissionResult or the activity will change the response code before it gets to your fragment